# Problema validando con bucle while en Python

Tags: python, while

Tengo un extraño problema con unas validaciones. Esto es un sistema para registrar materias de un alumno, tengo dos funciones q se ocupan de eso, el problema es q la función que debe validar las opciones a elegir no hace su trabajo y deja q se meta cualquier dato que le de la gana.

Esta es la funcion que llama al menu enviandole las materias que ya tiene el alumno, esta inicializado en [] porque inicialmente el alumno obviamente no tiene nada, pero hay q tener una referencia para no inscribir varias veces la misma materia.

```
def inscribir_materias():
    materias = [['Matématica', 0], ['Química', 1], ['Fisíca', 2], ['Historia', 3], ['Geografía', 4], ['Idiomas', 5], ['Biología', 6], ['Lógica', 7], ['Ed.Física', 8], ['Civico', 9]]
    inscritas = []
    print("SELECCIONE LAS MATERIAS")
    asignatura = -1
    centinela = 1
    opciones = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    k=0
    
    while centinela == True:
        asignatura = menu_materias(inscritas)
        if asignatura not in inscritas:
            inscritas.append(asignatura)
        else:
            print("Materia ya inscrita")
            asignatura = -1
        os.system("cls")
        print("""
            1- Inscribir otra manteria
            0- Salir
        """)
        centinela = int(input("Opción: "))
        if centinela == 0:
            centinela = False
```

Y aqui está el problema:

```
def menu_materias(inscritas):
    asignatura = -1
    opciones = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    k=0
    while asignatura not in opciones:#Simplemente esta linea actua como si no existe
        for i in materias:
            if k == len(materias):
                break
            for j in i:
                print(materias[k][1], "-", materias[k][0])
                k+=1
        print(f"{k} - Salir")
        try:                
            asignatura = int(input("Elija su opción: "))
        except:
            print("Favor introduzca una opción valida")
                
        if asignatura in inscritas:
            print("Ya tienes inscrita esta materia")
        else:
            return asignatura
```

No importa si meto cualquier cosa en 'asignatura' lo sigue dejando pasar, aunque no esté incluido en la lista de opciones. Ademas a veces no se le antoja imprimir completo el menu de opciones.

Comment: No entiendo que hace el índice j. Otra cosa, el if nunca va a darse por que ya tienes k=0, y no veo que nada modifique a k, para que el if pueda entrar cuando k sea igual al largo del array materias.

Comment: La 'i' representa cada una de las sublistas dentro de materias y la 'j' a los elementos dentro de cada una de ellas. Y 'k' es el contador dentro del for que itera a 'j' ya q i no es interable por ser una sublista y j está ocupado siendo el elemento interado.                    
materias = [['Matématica', 0], ['Química', 1], ['Fisíca', 2], ['Historia', 3], ['Geografía', 4], ['Idiomas', 5], ['Biología', 6], ['Lógica', 7], ['Ed.Física', 8], ['Civico', 9]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que la linea `while` actuara como si no existiese, simplemente es que no se puede cumplir la la condición. Para explicarlo mejor tengo el siguiente código:

```
lista1 = [1,2]
lista2 = [1,4,2,7,8,9]
if lista1 in lista2:
    print('Esta')
else:
    print('no esta')
```

Esto dará como resultado un "no esta", a pesar de que 1 y 2 si se encuentren dentro de `lista2`, esto se debe a que no se esta evaluando si cada elemento de `lista1` esta en `lista2` sino que se evalúa si el conjunto `[1,2]` se encuentra en `lista2` como un elemento, incluso si `lista1 = [1]` saldrá que no esta porque no se evalúa el 1, si no el `[1]`. Espero haberme dado a entender... Cuando haces:

```
while asignatura not in opciones
```

Sin importar el contenido dentro de la lista `asignatura` dará error porque estas evaluando si el conjunto entero se encuentra dentro de `opciones`, de igual forma pasa con esta linea:

```
 if asignatura in inscritas
```

Una solución es iterar la lista `asignatura` y por cada elemento hacer la comprobación.

EDIT: En resumen a diferencia del codigo presentado agregue un filtro para evitar valores que no estén dentro de las opciones y arregle el problema de seleccionar una materia ya inscrita.

```
import os
materias = [['Matématica', 0], ['Química', 1], ['Fisíca', 2], ['Historia', 3], ['Geografía', 4], ['Idiomas', 5], ['Biología', 6], ['Lógica', 7], ['Ed.Física', 8], ['Civico', 9]]

def inscribir_materias():
    print('DENTRO DE INSCRIBIR MATERIAS')
    
    inscritas = []
    print("SELECCIONE LAS MATERIAS")
    asignatura = -1
    centinela = 1
    opciones = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    k=0

    while centinela == True:
        asignatura = menu_materias(inscritas)
        print(asignatura)
        if asignatura !=None: #SE AGREGO ESTA VALIDACIONDONDE SI ES DISTINTO A None CONTINUAR EN CASO CONTRARIO PASAR
            if asignatura not in opciones: #SI SE LLEGA A METER UNA OPCION QUE NO ESTE EN OPCIONES NO CONTINUARA AL SIGUIENTE PASO Y POR TANTO NO ES AGREGADA A inscritas
                print('Esta no es una opción valida para materias')
                
            elif asignatura not in inscritas:
                inscritas.append(asignatura)
                print('inscritas: ',inscritas) #Esto es para dar seguimiento a las materias inscritas, puedes borrarlo
            else:
                print("Materia ya inscrita")
                asignatura = -ArithmeticError
        else:
            pass
        #os.system("cls") #Esto simeplemente lo comente porque me parecio molesto en mi entorno de programacion jajaja
        print("1- Inscribir otra manteria\n0- Salir")
        centinela = int(input("Opción: "))
        
        if centinela == 0:
            centinela = False

def menu_materias(inscritas):
    print('DENTRO DE MENU MATERIAS')
    asignatura = -1
    opciones = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    k=0
    while asignatura not in opciones:#Simplemente esta linea actua como si no existe
        for i in materias:
            if k == len(materias):
                break
            for j in i:
                print(materias[k][1], "-", materias[k][0])
                k+=1
        print(f"{k} - Salir")
        try:                
            asignatura = int(input("Elija su opción: "))
        except:
            print("Favor introduzca una opción valida")
                
        if asignatura in inscritas:
            print("\nYa tienes inscrita esta materia")
        else:
            return asignatura

inscribir_materias() #para ejecutar inscribir_materias()...
```

Sobre lo que se menciona en el comentario sobre un problema en el `while` no se me presento ninguno aparte de que si trataba de colocar una opción que no estuviera en `opciones`.

Comment: Creo q ya entiendo el problema. El codigo q escribi solo funciona una vez, porque una vez que 'inscritas' empieza a acumular elementos, el while no puede cumplir su funcion. Solo funciona cuando se evalua un unico elemento, no una lista. Gracias

Comment: Eso es correcto, podrías hacer un `for` que itere en cada elemento de inscritas y hacer la validación con el `while` de cada elemento. Si esta respuesta resuelve tu problema u alguna otra que publiquen no olvides marcar una respuesta como correcta~

Comment: El problema es q aunque asignatura no es una lista, el bucle while no se mantiene, sino que deja pasar lo que le pongo. Si pongo la opcion 11, que no existe en la lista de opciones, igual lo deja entrar.

Comment: Trato de replicar el código pero en ningún momento declaras `materias` dentro de `menu_materias(inscritas)` acaso es una variable global? solo veo una declaración de materias localmente en `inscribir_materias()`

Comment: Lo moví fuera de las funciones.

Comment: Vale replique el codigo y funciona a la perfección menos cuando intentas seleccionar una materia que ya esta inscrita, la cual agrega un valor "none" a la lista, este es tu problema?

Comment: Eso y que como dije, el while no mantiene el ciclo a pesar q meta cualquier opcion incorrecta en asignatura. Pero ya lo arreglé, solo le dije q si asignatura es None, no la cuente.

Comment: Vale, conseguí arreglar el problema de que no puedan agregar valores fuera de los permitidos en las materias, y el caso del valor None si se repite una asignatura ya agregada, actualizare mi respuesta.

Comment: Puede ser un error de compilacion entonces. Quiza al reiniciar la computadora funcione. Gracias :)

Comment: Lo reinicié, aun hace lo mismo, no se q carajo pasa con Python q interpreta mal mi codigo. Lo probé con la cmd y el while sigue dejando pasar valores que no estan en 'opciones'

Comment: @Casselius seria un gusto seguir ayudándote pero es mejor evitar extender los comentarios de un post y en este momento estoy fuera de casa, si para la noche aun no resuelves tu problema escribe por aquí y seguimos en un chat de stackoverflow o donde te parezca y revisamos el código con calma

Comment: No hay problema, de todos modos ya lo arreglé, tuve que cambiar la estructura de la funcion porque el while no me hacia caso, asi q me las arreglé para usar otros metodos. Actualizaré el post con los cambios que hice.

Comment: Fino, si resolviste el problema entonces se puede dar el post por terminado, éxito programando!